# Change default "My template" directory for Arcmap layout view?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

So the default directory for "My templates" for switching the layouts in layout view is C:\Users\xxxx\appdata\raoming\esri\desktop..... so premade layouts can be accessed quickly. I need these same templates across a couple computers with access to the same network. Is it possible to point this default template folder to another drive, so that they all share the same templates?

Comment: This answers how to change the location for the "Templates" and not for the "My Templates". It would be nice to know how to change the location for "My Templates" as well (Or how to change ArcMAP to let "Templates" be default selected - now it is "My Templates" which is selected. (And the users may be confused when there is no templates listed).

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways of doing this

**Advanced ArcMap Settings**

1. Go to C:\Program
   Files\ArcGIS\Desktop**10.0**\Utilities\AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe
   (Depending on what version of ArcGIS you are using)
2. Go to the System paths tab
3. Click on the browse button for Templates path
4. Browse to the folder location
5. Click Apply

**Registry Key**

Create a Registry Key for the key **TemplateDir** which can be found in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ESRI\Desktop**10.0**\ArcMap\Settings

The templates will now be available when you open a new map document
[image]

Comment: I see. Is there a way to embed this in a document? So that one certain mxd file will always point to this custom template folder location?

Comment: When you open up a new map document, you will be able to choose what template you want to use. (Image added to answer).